# Adding X509 extensions in BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509

I'm trying to generate x509 certificates using BouncyCastle (Java). It mostly works - I can generate public/private keys, generate signing requests, set validity, subjectKeyInfo, basic constraints, extended key usage.

But I'm stuck on adding AIA and CDP extensions - it adds the URLs but there's something wrong in the formatting - I get:

```
            Authority Information Access:
                0u..+.....0..ihttp://sslulike-cacache.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ukfedtest/299b1033-a09d-47ed-b6d7-7505d7d574f5
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:
                0s0q.o.mhttp://sslulike-cacache.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ukfedtest/299b1033-a09d-47ed-b6d7-7505d7d574f5.crl
```

As you can see, it mangles the beginning of the URL and misses **Full Name:** for CDP, **CA Issuers** for AIA.
versus a proper cert:

```
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-4536.crl

           Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
                CA Issuers - URI:http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt
```

Here's my code:

```
            builder.addExtension(Extension.create(Extension.authorityInfoAccess, false, 
                    new AccessDescription(
                            X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_ad_caIssuers, 
                            new GeneralName(GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier,
                                    new DERIA5String(org.getCertURLBase()+org.getOrgId()+"/"+keyId)
                            )
            )));

            DistributionPoint cdp = new DistributionPoint(new DistributionPointName(DistributionPointName.FULL_NAME, new DERIA5String(org.getCertURLBase()+org.getOrgId()+"/"+keyId+".crl")), null, null);
            builder.addExtension(Extension.create(Extension.cRLDistributionPoints, false, new CRLDistPoint(new DistributionPoint[]{cdp})));
```

(The input strings build correct URLs, I've checked that)

Any ideas what I'm missing?

thanks,

Jim

Comment: CDP is actually a _sequence of_ DistributionPoint; you need to `new CRLDistPoint` from an array of DistributionPoint, here with only one element. Similarly AIA (or SIA, if implemented) is a sequence of AccessDescription; it has ctors from either an array of AccessDescription or a single one. (I'm surprised they offer this choice for AIA but not for CDP, when I've never seen a cert with more than one element in CDP whereas most, like your example, have two in AIA. But such is life.)

Comment: what version of java are you using? in java 11+ you may not need Bouncy Castle at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK- got this working. It looks like BouncyCastle is buggy here, my solutions are not consistent or not very tidy but do appear to work.

CDP:

```
    protected static Extension makeCDP(String url) {
        try {
            byte[] encodedUrl = url.getBytes("US-ASCII");
            if (encodedUrl.length > 119)
                throw new Exception("URL too long");
            
            byte[] payload = new byte[encodedUrl.length + 10];
            int offset = 0;
            payload[offset++] = (byte)0x30;
            payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.length + 8);
            payload[offset++] = (byte)0x30;
            payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.length + 6);
            payload[offset++] = (byte)0xA0;
            payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.length + 4);
            payload[offset++] = (byte)0xA0;
            payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.length + 2);
            payload[offset++] = (byte)0x86;
            payload[offset++] = (byte)(encodedUrl.length);
            for (;offset < payload.length;offset++)
                payload[offset] = encodedUrl[offset-10];

            return new Extension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.31"),false, payload);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

AIA:

```
    protected static Extension makeAIA(String url) {
        DERTaggedObject caIssuers= new DERTaggedObject(false, 6, new DERIA5String(url));
        ASN1EncodableVector caIssuers_ASN = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        caIssuers_ASN.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2"));
        caIssuers_ASN.add(caIssuers);
        DERSequence caIssuersSeq = new DERSequence(caIssuers_ASN);
        
        ASN1EncodableVector accessSyn_ASN = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        accessSyn_ASN.add(caIssuersSeq);
        DERSequence AIASyntaxSeq = new DERSequence(accessSyn_ASN);

        try {
            return new Extension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1"), false, new DEROctetString(AIASyntaxSeq));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```